# npm ERR! in docker-compose

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and i'm trying to build containers from a `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.0'

volumes: 
  mongodb:
  esdb:
    driver: local

services: 
  app:
    build: ./
    command: npm run dev
    container_name: beez-backend
    networks:
      - custom      
    volumes:
      - ./:/beez-backend/
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
      - "9229:9229"
    external_links:  
      - mongo 
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file:
      ./dev.env

  # MongoDB image config - this container will exposed as external so other container will use it 
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: beez-backend-mongo
    ports: 
    - "27036:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db 
    networks:
      - custom

networks:
  custom:
    external: true
```

And my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:dubnium-alpine

LABEL maintainer="XXX"


RUN mkdir -p /beez-backend

RUN npm install nodemon -g

WORKDIR /beez-backend


COPY package.json /beez-backend
RUN npm install 

COPY . /beez-backend

EXPOSE 3030
EXPOSE 9229

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

package.json dependencies -

```json
{
  "name": "XXX",
  "description": "XXX",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "",
  "main": "src",
  "keywords": [
    "feathers",
    "beez"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "X",
    "email": "X"
  },
  "contributors": [],
  "bugs": {},
  "directories": {
    "lib": "src",
    "test": "test/"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^11.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run eslint && NODE_ENV= npm run mocha",
    "eslint": "eslint src/. test/. --config .eslintrc.json",
    "dev": "nodemon -L --delay 2 --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 src/",
    "start": "node src/",
    "mocha": "mocha test/ --recursive --exit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@feathersjs/authentication": "^4.5.2",
    "@feathersjs/authentication-local": "^4.5.2",
    "@feathersjs/authentication-oauth": "^4.5.2",
    "@feathersjs/configuration": "^4.5.2",
    "@feathersjs/errors": "^4.5.2",
    "@feathersjs/express": "^4.5.2",
    "@feathersjs/feathers": "^4.5.2",
    "@feathersjs/socketio": "^4.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cron": "^1.7.2",
    "exceljs": "^3.8.1",
    "feathers-authentication-hooks": "^1.0.0",
    "feathers-authentication-management": "^2.0.1",
    "feathers-hooks-common": "^4.20.7",
    "feathers-mailer": "^3.0.1",
    "feathers-mongoose": "^8.1.0",
    "feathers-populate-hook": "^0.5.3",
    "feathers-swagger": "^1.1.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "form-data": "^2.5.1",
    "helmet": "^3.21.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongodb-core": "^3.2.7",
    "mongoosastic": "^4.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-google-storage": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid": "^1.0.3",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "npm": "^6.14.2",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "validator": "^11.1.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "mocha": "^6.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5"
  }
}
```

It goes through the steps properly until step 7/11 which is `RUN npm install`. Here is gives the error:

> ```
> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near /..UyIRBcPKVK9LxycWnlezO'
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-21T17_48_59_909Z-debug.log
> ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build:
>        The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
> ```

I tried the `npm cache clean --force` and running `docker-compose up` but it didn't change. I also tried adding the line `RUN npm cache clean` right before the `RUN npm install` in the Dockerfile but it still didn't work. Both the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file are on the same directory.

Comment: Does it works outside of docker? Can you add the complete npm error?
At first, I think your package.json file is not a valid json

Comment: @jmaitrehenry Yes npm install works elsewhere

Comment: @Joseph cant you post your full file. Or error occurred at line?

Comment: AFAIK, `npm install` gets all data from package.lock, so maybe your package.lock is corrupt. What happens if you try `npm update`?

Comment: It updates when i run `npm update`

Answer (score 2):

Try below steps :

1. `$ npm cache clean --force`
   or
   $ `npm cache verify`
2. `$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
3. `$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`
4. Delete node_modules
5. Run `$ npm install`